# How to write inline if statement for print?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, inline

I need to print some stuff only when a boolean variable is set to `True`. So, after looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319214/shorter-more-pythonic-way-of-writing-an-if-statements), I tried with a simple example:

```
>>> a = 100
>>> b = True
>>> print a if b
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print a if b
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Same thing if I write `print a if b==True`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Comment: Good question, complex answers... a straight one would be "the else part is mandatory".

Comment: A good thing to note is that the if **expression** works in `lambda`, but **not** the one-line statement.

Comment: @mins the accepted answer seems pretty straightforward to me. For a question this important, the top answers should include that kind of information.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I added an answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1082, accepted):

Python does **not** have a trailing `if` **statement**.

There are two kinds of `if` in Python:

1. `if` statement:

   ```
   if condition: statement
   if condition:
       block
   ```
2. `if` **expression** (introduced in Python 2.5)

   ```
   expression_if_true if condition else expression_if_false
   ```

And note, that both `print a` and `b = a` are statements. Only the `a` part is an expression. So if you write

```
print a if b else 0
```

it means

```
print (a if b else 0)
```

and similarly when you write

```
x = a if b else 0
```

it means

```
x = (a if b else 0)
```

Now what would it print/assign if there was no `else` clause? The print/assignment is **still there**.

And note, that if you don't want it to be there, you can always write the regular `if` statement on a single line, though it's less readable and there is really no reason to avoid the two-line variant.

Comment: I think that `if condition: statement` does not work in case of multiline statements.

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to use if, simply use boolean logic like I show below in my examples.

Comment: @JanHudec If Python doesn't have a trailing `if`, then why does this work: [`print [i for i in range(10) if i%2]`](https://repl.it/BLMh)? I wish they'd allow it outside of comprehensions...

Comment: @mbomb007, that is not a trailing if *statement* either. It is simply part of the list (or generator) comprehension. Note that the thing before the if is not a statement, it is two expressions with `for` between them.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot. Would print ("a " + (id+ "_" if id else "") + " b") be considered a good solution if I want to ad an "id_" to a string if id is not none?

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr, yes, that sounds reasonable.

Comment: Can anybody help me understand why b=a is a statement and not an expression?

Comment: @KaranSingh, because python grammar defines it that way.

Comment: can the else part be omitted? To write like
print a if a

Comment: @ApurvaKunkulol, would you be so kind and *read the question again*? It shows precisely that syntax—and the syntax error it produces. Ergo, no, it can't.

Comment: I ended up doing something like  `print("reason why I do nothing") if not_good_reason else do_something()`

Comment: It's worth noting that 'else' is required. It would be convenient to simply use 'if' in some cases (e.g. c += a if b), but alas.

Comment: @KaranSingh, the `a=b` not being an expression is a helpful syntactic device in Python, and learnt from other languages (C) where assignment and testing could be mingled and mixed up.

Answer (score 140):

Inline if-else *EXPRESSION* must always contain else clause, e.g:

```
a = 1 if b else 0
```

If you want to leave your 'a' variable value unchanged - assing old 'a' value (else is still required by syntax demands):

```
a = 1 if b else a
```

This piece of code leaves **a** unchanged when b turns to be False.

Comment: Oh. But what if I don't want anything to happen in the else branch? I need something like: `print a if b`

Comment: `else a` would be better then `else 0`

Comment: `if b: print a` Just need a simple if in that case

Comment: @RickyRobinson, if you want nothing to be changed - just assign old 'a' value: a = 1 if b else a

Comment: Fixing the answer, because it's almost good if it wasn't for the word 'statement' which made it totally bad. The gist of the question is that it's *not* a statement.

Comment: +1-1: Good for pointing out that the else expression is mandatory, but not ok for not providing the answer for the case in question: print "nothing" (something along the lines of `""` or `None`, see details in other answers).

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to use if, simply use boolean logic like I show below in my examples.

Comment: Is this faster than just using
if b:
    a = b
else:
   a = c
?
(not able to do multi-line edit here)

Answer (score 35):

The 'else' statement is mandatory. You can do stuff like this :

```
>>> b = True
>>> a = 1 if b else None
>>> a
1
>>> b = False
>>> a = 1 if b else None
>>> a
>>>
```

**EDIT:**

Or, depending of your needs, you may try:

```
>>> if b: print(a)
```

Answer (score 24):

If you don't want to `from __future__ import print_function` you can do the following:

```
a = 100
b = True
print a if b else "",  # Note the comma!
print "see no new line"
```

Which prints:

```
100 see no new line
```

If you're not aversed to `from __future__ import print_function` or are using python 3 or later:

```
from __future__ import print_function
a = False
b = 100
print(b if a else "", end = "")
```

Adding the else is the only change you need to make to make your code syntactically correct, you need the else for the conditional expression (the "in line if else blocks")

The reason I didn't use `None` or `0` like others in the thread have used, is because using `None/0` would cause the program to `print None` or `print 0` in the cases where `b` is `False`.

If you want to read about this topic I've included a [link](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/pep-308.html) to the release notes for the patch that this feature was added to Python.

The 'pattern' above is very similar to the pattern shown in PEP 308:

> This syntax may seem strange and backwards; why does the condition go
>   in the middle of the expression, and not in the front as in C's c ? x
>   : y? The decision was checked by applying the new syntax to the
>   modules in the standard library and seeing how the resulting code
>   read. In many cases where a conditional expression is used, one value
>   seems to be the 'common case' and one value is an 'exceptional case',
>   used only on rarer occasions when the condition isn't met. The
>   conditional syntax makes this pattern a bit more obvious:
>
> contents = ((doc + '\n') if doc else '')

So I think overall this is a reasonable way of approching it but you can't argue with the simplicity of:

```
if logging: print data
```

Comment: Thanks. The thing here is that `print ""` will still print something: a blank line.

Comment: Thanks. The `end` argumnt in `print` only appears in Python 3.x, right?

Comment: aye, I'm more of a 2.7 man hence the  `from __future__ import print_function`

Answer (score 19):

You can write an inline ternary operator like so:

```py
sure = True

# inline operator
is_true = 'yes' if sure else 'no'

# print the outcome
print(is_true)
```

Answer (score 15):

This can be done with [string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9244925/2000793). It works with the % notation as well as [.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (new to 3.6)

```
print '%s' % (a if b else "")
```

or

```
print '{}'.format(a if b else "")
```

or

```
print(f'{a if b else ""}')
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with formatting; you could just do `print a if b else ""`. Which is exactly what Noelkd's answer does.

Comment: @melpomene but printing "" ads a new line, that can be avoided using `print "",` (colon) for Python2, and using `print("", end="")` for Python3.

Answer (score 14):

You can use:

```
print (1==2 and "only if condition true" or "in case condition is false")
```

Just as well you can keep going like:

```
print (1==2 and "aa" or ((2==3) and "bb" or "cc"))
```

Real world example:

```
>>> print ("%d item%s found." % (count, (count!=1 and 's' or '')))
1 item found.
>>> count = 2
>>> print ("%d item%s found." % (count, (count!=1 and 's' or '')))
2 items found.
```

Answer (score 13):

Since 2.5 you can use [equivalent of C’s ”?:”](https://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator) [ternary conditional operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394809/55075) and the syntax is:

```
[on_true] if [expression] else [on_false]
```

So your example is fine, but you've to simply add `else`, like:

```
print a if b else ''
```

Comment: Note that the `print ''` will still print a newline, which is avoided in the answer by Noelkd.

Answer (score 6):

For your case this works:

```
a = b or 0
```

**Edit:** How does this work?

In the question

```
b = True
```

So evaluating

```
b or 0
```

results in

```
True
```

which is assigned to `a`.

If `b == False?`, `b or 0` would evaluate to the second operand `0` which would be assigned to `a`.

Comment: Ugliness and errorproneness of this expression is the reason why we have conditional expression in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

Try this . It might help you

```
a=100
b=True

if b:
   print a
```

Answer (score 6):

You're simply overcomplicating.

```
if b:
   print a
```

Comment: Of course that's the easiest option. I think that at the time (august 2012) I wanted to do something like: `if DEBUG: print something`

Comment: Duplicated answer? See that by SkariaArun, and also a comment.

Answer (score 6):

```
print a if b
File "<stdin>", line 1
    print a if b
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

**Answer**

If your `print` statement must print an empty line when the expression is false, the correct syntax is:

```
print(a if b else '')
```

The reason is you're using the [conditional **expression**](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) which has two mandatory clauses, one when `b` is true preceding `if`, one when `b` is false following `else`.

Both clauses are themselves expressions. The conditional expression is also called the *ternary operator*, making it clear it operates on three elements, a condition and two expressions. In your code the `else` part is missing.

However I guess your idea was not to print an empty line when the expression was false, but to do nothing. In that case you have to use `print` within a [conditional **statement**](https://docs.python.org//3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if), in order to condition its execution to the result of the evaluation of `b`.

---

**Details: Expression vs. statement**

The conditional statement can be used without the `else` part:

- The `if` statement is a compound statement with further instructions to execute depending on the result of the condition evaluation.
- It is not required to have an `else` clause where the appropriate additional instructions are provided. Without it, when the condition is false no further instructions are executed after the test.
- The conditional expression is an expression. Any expression must be convertible to a final value, regardless of the subsequent use of this value by subsequent statements (here the `print` statement).
- Python makes no assumption about what should be the value of the expression when the condition is false.

You could have used an `if` statement this way:

```
if b: print(a)
```

Note the difference:

- There is no instructions executed by the `if` statement when the condition is false, nothing is printed because `print` is not called.
- In a `print` statement with a conditional expression `print(a if b else '')`, `print` is always executed. What it prints is the `if` conditional expression. This expression is evaluated prior to executing the `print` statement. So `print` outputs an empty line when the condition is false.

---

Note your other attempt `print(a if b==True)` is just equivalent to the first one.

Since `b==True` is syntactically equivalent to `b`, I guess Python interpreter just replaces the former by the latter before execution. Your second attempt likely comes down to a repeat of the first one.

Answer (score 3):

You always need an `else` in an inline if:

```
a = 1 if b else 0
```

But an easier way to do it would be `a = int(b)`.

Comment: -1: Easier. And totally unreadable. And not what the asker wanted anyway.

Comment: ITYM `a = int(bool(b))`.

Answer (score 2):

hmmm, you can do it with a **list comprehension**. This would only make sense if you had a real range.. but it does do the job:

```
print([a for i in range(0,1) if b])
```

or using just those two variables:

```
print([a for a in range(a,a+1) if b])
```

Answer (score -2):

Well why don't you simply write:

```
if b:
    print a
else:
    print 'b is false'
```