# Python: Inline if statement else do nothing

Tags: python, django, if-statement, conditional-statements, inline

Assigning a Django Model's field to a value if it matches a condition.

```
g = Car.objects.get(pk=1234)
g.data_version = my_dict['dataVersion'] if my_dict else expression_false # Do nothing??
```

How do I do nothing in that case? We can't do `if conditional else pass`.

I know I can do:

```
if my_dict:
    g.data_version = my_dict['dataVersion']
```

but I was wondering if there was a way to do inline `expression_true if conditional else do nothing`.

Comment: Nope, can't do it in Python.

Comment: You can always write `if my_dict: g.data_version = ...` on the same line if you want, but that goes against the Python style.

Comment: why would you want to do this? ... it doesnt make sense...

Comment: The "inline if statement" is properly called a conditional expression; it's not a statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write inline if statement for print?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880430/how-to-write-inline-if-statement-for-print)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't do exactly what you are describing, as it wouldn't make sense. You are assigning to the variable `g.data_version`... so you must assign something. What you describe would be like writing:

```
g.data_version =  # There is nothing else here
```

Which is obviously invalid syntax. And really, there's no reason to do it. You should either do:

```
if my_dict:
    g.data_version = my_dict['dataVersion']
```

or

```
g.data_version = my_dict['dataVersion'] if my_dict else None # or 0 or '' depending on what data_version should be.
```

Technically, you could also do:

```
g.data_version = my_dict['dataVersion'] if my_dict else g.data_version
```

if you only want to update `g.data_version` if your dict exists, but this is less readable and elegant than just using a normal if statement.