# Python If Statement - Syntax Error

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

Currently stuck with this syntax error, error is posted below the code.

```
@property
def data_rows(self):
    for d in rlgenevautils.to_csv_dict(self.data_file):
        trade_dt  = rlcore.str2dt(d['EventDate'])
        settle_dt = rlcore.str2dt(d['ActualSettleDate'])

        yield (str(d['_UDF_SGCP_ID_'])
              ,str(d['_UDF_Execution_ID_'])
              ,str(d['_UDF_PB_ID_'])
              ,str(d['_UDF_Fund_Admin_ID_'])
              ,str(d['_Portfolio_NameSort_'])
              ,str(d['_Strategy_Code_'])
              ,str(d['_LocationAccount_NameSort_'])
              ,str(d['_Broker_NameSort_'])
              ,str(d['_Investment_Code_'])
              ,trade_dt.isoformat(' ')
              ,settle_dt.isoformat(' ')
              ,rlcore.str2float(d['ABSQuantityForCalcCurrentFace'])
              ,max(rlcore.str2float(d['ABSQuantityForCalcCurrentFace']),rlcore.str2float(d['OriginalFace']))
              ,rlcore.str2float(d['ABSQuantityForCalcCurrentFace'])/max(rlcore.str2float(d['ABSQuantityForCalcCurrentFace']),rlcore.str2float(d['OriginalFace']))
              ,rlcore.str2float(d['Price'])
              ,rlcore.str2float(d['ABSAccruedInterestForCalcCurrentFace'])
              ,if str(d['_Investment_InvestmentGroup_']) == "AssetBacked":
                   rlcore.str2float(d['ABSQuantityForCalcCurrentFace']) * rlcore.str2float(d['Price']) / 100
               else:
                   rlcore.str2float(d['NetCashAmount'])
              ,rlcore.str2float(d['ABSAccruedInterestForCalcCurrentFace']) + rlcore.str2float(d['txtNetCashPreAccrued'])
              )

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File ".\sg\rec_and_liquidity\geneva_trade.py", line 64
      ,if str(d['_Investment_InvestmentGroup_']) == "AssetBacked":
       ^
```

Code above, unable to figure out what my syntax error is on the if statement. Error message will be pasted as comment shortly

Comment: Please edit the original post with the error. The comment box strips out whitespace, which may be useful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Ok, one momenti will update shortly

Comment: It looks like you are trying to `yield` with an inline `if`. What you have is not the correct syntax. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11880682/651848) shows how to do an inline `if`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this now. Learning on the job today.

Comment: As a side note, it looks like you're making a lot of things more complicated than they need to be. For example, what is `d['_Investment_InvestmentGroup_']`? If it's already a `str`, why are you calling `str` on it? More generally, there's probably a good way to define the types of each "column" and convert them all in a simple expression instead of one massive ugly thing like this.

Comment: Side note: it's a little weird to put the commas at the beginning of the line instead of the end.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't put a statement in the middle of an expression.

---

For simple cases, there is an `if` expression that, being an expression, *can* be used in the middle of an expression. In your case:

```
(rlcore.str2float(d['ABSQuantityForCalcCurrentFace']) * rlcore.str2float(d['Price']) / 100
 if str(d['_Investment_InvestmentGroup_']) == "AssetBacked"
 else rlcore.str2float(d['NetCashAmount']))
```

---

For more complicated cases, move the `if` statement upward and store a temporary value in a variable, then use that variable in the expression (exactly as you're already doing for, each, `trade_dt`):

```
if str(d['_Investment_InvestmentGroup_']) == "AssetBacked":
    priceval = rlcore.str2float(d['ABSQuantityForCalcCurrentFace']) * rlcore.str2float(d['Price']) / 100
else:
    priceval = rlcore.str2float(d['NetCashAmount'])
```

… then just use `priceval` in the `yield`.

---

However, no matter how you solve this, your code is a huge unreadable mess. You have at least three different conversion methods you're using repeatedly; if you discover that you're formatting dates or strings or whatever wrong, you'll need to change that in dozens of places. You'd probably do better off with a mapping of column names to either types, or converters, and then just generate the values by dynamically looking up each converter. For example:

```
_COLUMNS = {'_UDF_SGCP_ID_': str,
            '_UDF_Execution_ID_': str,
            # ...
            'EventDate': datetime.datetime,
            # ...
            }

_CONVERTERS = {str: str, 
               datetime.datetime: lambda val: rlcore.str2dt(val).isoformat(),
               # ...}

def _converted(d, col):
    val = d[col]
    converter = _CONVERTERS[_COLUMNS[col]]
    return converter(val)
```

And now you can just do this:

```
yield(_converted(d, col) for col in (        
    '_UDF_SGCP_ID_',
    '_UDF_Execution_ID_',
    # ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't include an `if` statement inside an expression like that.  If you want to include it in an expression, you need to use a conditional *expression*:

```
(rlcore.str2float(d['ABSQuantityForCalcCurrentFace']) * rlcore.str2float(d['Price']) / 100) if str(d['_Investment_InvestmentGroup_']) == "AssetBacked" elserlcore.str2float(d['NetCashAmount'])
```

However, this is not very readable.  It would be better to move your if statement to before the `yield`, assign the result to a variable, and use that variable in the `yield`.

Comment: Thanks! That is much more efficient than what I was thinking of!

Answer (score 1):

'if' is a statement, and creating tuple this way you can use only expressions.

Change your code like follows:

```
if condition:
   something
else:
   something2
```

to

```
 something if condition else something2
```