# Neatest (or most readable yet still one line way) to print second tuple if first one false

Tags: python, python-3.x

e.g. pictures this:

```
def some_operation(var) -> (bool, String):
    return False, "This is a test"


success, error_message = someOperation("aVar")
if not success:
    print(error_message)
```

I feel there must be a way to do something in one line that prints msg if err == false. If there were defined you could do

```
`success or print(error_message)`
```

Maybe some sort of wrapper or lambda helper to take the method call that returns the two element tuple?

Comment: `if not success: print(error_message)` can be written in one line

Comment: I meant along with the method call too

Comment: What you have is fine. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11880682/1832539) to help further explain.

Comment: @MitchellCurrie Your example does not include the method call either.

Comment: Sorry, I gave the line as an example of what I'd wish to do, if it could incorporate the call too.

Comment: Readability counts. There's no need to squeeze anything into one line.

Comment: I'm calling it a lot of times in unit tests. So I guess if I wrapped it into a helper eval_method( method )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best practice to use what you're using right now, but anyway, this is Python, a.k.a home of the one-liners (actually, it has second place after [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29))...

```
(lambda success, error_message: None if success else print(error_message))(*someOperation("aVar"))
```

Comment: You're right, this is closest to what I was after although @Paul effort is good too, this squashes output if it's empty. I should more effort int the surround functions than make it one line.

Answer (score 0):

Not really good practice, but this comes close to what you want:

```
print ''.join((not success)*message for success,message in [fn()])
```

To test it out:

```
retGood = lambda: (True, "that was good")
retBad = lambda: (False, "that was not so good")

print 'Success -> ' + ''.join((not success)*message for success,message in [retGood()])
print 'Failure -> ' + ''.join((not success)*message for success,message in [retBad()])
```

Prints:

```
Success -> 
Failure -> that was not so good
```

It is not quite what you asked for, as it does print a blank line if success is returned as True. But it *is* a one-liner to print the error message only if a False success is returned.

Comment: Interesting technique of zipping the string