# Compare two strings within a print statement and print values accordingly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looping through each row (line containing "fields" separated by spaces) inside a data file and would like to compare a substring of one field with another static value. If the comparison is true I would like to print a string 'X' otherwise 'Y'. Just wondering how can it be done using Python. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Code :-**

```
for i in inputm[1:]:    
    print('\n',i[0].split(':')[0]
              ,str(datetime.strptime(i[0].split(':')[1],'%Y%m%d'))[:10]
              ,i[1],round(sum( float(v) if v else 0.0 for v in i[2:6])/4,2)
              ,i[6][0:23]
          )
```

**Input :-**

```
1:20160101  123 10  20  0   0   http://www.google.com/favorites 
2:20170101  234 20  30  10  0   http://www.doodle.com/favorites
```

**Output :-**

```
1 2016-01-01 123 7.5 Correct
2 2017-01-01 234 17.5 InCorrect
```

**Comments :-** 
I am really interested in this piece of code.

```
  i[6][0:23]
```

Would like to compare the above substring with http://www.google.com and if they match then print Correct else InCorrect.

Comment: tuple inside a file? Substring of a column? What exactly are you talking about? These words have meanings, please stick to standard terminology. And what do you mean within a print statement? First, `print` is a function not a statement in Python 3, and I'm not sure why you want to do it inside anyway.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I am not demanding for code here... Being new to Python I explored and browsed on google but really didnt find anything to do conditional printing with in a print statement....

Comment: The more expressions you cram into a single statement, the less comprehensible they all become.

Comment: You're trying to add something to code that's already present in it, so you apparently neither wrote nor read it. It looks very much like a code-writing request to me.

Answer (score -1):

Python offers a ternary-style expression syntax that looks like this:

```
value1 if condition else value2
```

You can use that to print:

```
x = some_number()
print( 'X' if x < 10 else 'Y' )
```

Comment: the question already includes a conditional expression, so presumably, the author knows about them...

Comment: Nah. OP got that from another question about 30 mins ago.

Comment: Yes, it looks like OP picked up Python earlier today and is trying to produce code by getting SO to write it for him/her. That doesn't make this answer relevant (if it were, it'd be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880430/how-to-write-inline-if-statement-for-print) anyway).

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to do everything in one go, divide and conquer:

```
# read the lines
with open('myfile.txt', 'rb') as fp:
    rows = fp.readlines()

# split the lines into fields
rows = [row.split() for row in rows]

# create a function to format field values
def fmt_row(row):
    res = []
    res += row[0].split(':')  # split the first field on :
    res += [float(field) for field in row[1:-1]]  # convert all but first/last field to float
    date = res[1]
    res[1] = '%s-%s-%s' % (date[:4], date[4:6], date[6:])
    return res

# convert/format all the rows
rows = [fmt_row(row) for row in rows]

# finally create the output
output = [[
    row[0],   # first output field
    row[1],   # second..
    round(sum(row[2:-1]/4), 2),
    'Correct' if row[-1] == 'http://www.google.com/favorites' else 'InCorrect'
] for row in rows]

# print the output?
print '\n'.join([' '.join(row) for row in output])
```

Comment: It doesn't work...

Comment: @Teja:  "It doesn't work" is not a useful problem statement, and with over 150 questions to your name, you should know that.

Answer (score -2):

You could use inline if statement -

```
"Correct" if some_condition else "InCorrect"
```

This will return "Correct" if condition is True.

But I really suggest you to use some intermediate variables. Your code is unreadable.