# is there a way to print the value being evaluated in an if statement without having to store it in a variable?

Tags: python, if-statement

This might be a silly question, but I am wondering if there is a way to print or use the value being evaluated in an if statement without having to store it in a variable first before evaluating it?

something similar to this sort of syntax:

```
if value_of_really_long_expression == True:
    print(value_of_really_long_expression)
```

of course this can be achieved by:

```
x = value_of_really_long_expression

if x == True:
    print(x)
```

purely out of interest/curiosity, I am wondering if this is even possible

Comment: Nope, not in the stable releases of python in any case. Though irony being, if you entered the `if` block on an `==` check, you already *know* what the expression evaluated to. However, i'm assuming this is just a glorified simplified example.

Comment: You may be interested in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11880430/4636715 . At least you can reduce to a one-liner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible; there are no implicit references one could use. Python 3.8, though, introduces an assignment expression which at least streamlines the assignment:

```
if (x := really_long_expression):
    print(x)
```

The scope of `x` remains the same as if you had written

```
x = really_long_expression
if x:
    print(x)
```

that is, `x` is not local to the body of the `if` statement.

Comment: awesome...was not aware of this - waiting to accept answer (Time limit) :)

Comment: Strictly speaking, you have to wait a few months yet before being able to use this officially anyway :)

Comment: understood, but excited for 3.8 :D