# Using generator for Switch in Python

Tags: python

I try do to the switch using generator in Python but i failed!Lol

I see a code in internet but i don't undestand the for loop

```
def get_tipo_dia(dia):
    dias = {
        (1, 7): 'final de semana',
        tuple(range(2, 7)): 'dia de semana'
    }
    generator = (tipo for numero ,tipo in dias.items() if dia in numero)  #This part i cant uderstand!!
    return next(generator, '**dia invalido**')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for dia in range(0, 9):
        print(f'{dia}: {get_tipo_dia(dia)}')
```

Comment: Is this the part you don't understand? [if expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880430/how-to-write-inline-if-statement-for-print) - or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
generator = (tipo for numero ,tipo in dias.items() if dia in numero)
```

The generator enumerates the key/value pairs in `dias`,filters out the pairs where the key does not contain the value in `dia` and emits the corresponding value. The generator only performs this action when its `__next__` method is called, either implicitly through a loop (e.g., `for`, as part of a list comprension, as a parameter to a function that consumes iterables) or by using `next()`.

```
next(generator, '**dia invalido**')
```

Consumes 1 item from the generator or raises StopIteration.

This is the same thing as

```
def get_tipo_dia(dia):
    dias = {
        (1, 7): 'final de semana',
        tuple(range(2, 7)): 'dia de semana'
    }
    for numero, tipo in dias.items():
        if dia in numero:
            return tipo
    else:
        raise StopIteration()
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this helps, but here's the same logic re-written with explicitly constructed list first, and then that list is converted to an iterator.

```py
def get_tipo_dia(dia):
    dias = {
        (1, 7): 'final de semana',
        tuple(range(2, 7)): 'dia de semana'
    }

    generator = list()
    for numero , tipo in dias.items():
        if dia in numero:
            generator.append(tipo)

    generator = iter(generator)

    return next(generator, '**dia invalido**')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for dia in range(0, 9):
        print(f'{dia}: {get_tipo_dia(dia)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `tipo` in

```
generator = (tipo for numero ,tipo in dias.items() if dia in numero)
```

checks the `type` of variable used for `numero`, which would be an `int` as well as the `type` for the items in `dias` which gets the values of `1` and `7` that returns the `str` `'final de semana'` which would be the weekend days; and the range of the integers `2` through `7` which are the days of the week. If either of those are not returned, then the string `'**dia invalido**'` would return. The console then prints the returned string. I'm guessing you are confused mainly by the `if` expression. Please read about those [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp).