# Can we use if-else keywords inside print()

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Can we use if-else keywords inside `print()`? For example: `print(if age<=18:)` or something like that.

Comment: Do you want to conditionally call `print` or have whatever is printed be conditional? Please add some examples with your expected output for each case.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more cause i am newbie to python?

Comment: ohh if you mean you need more examples then here they are

Comment: Do you want to print something over a condition or the printed text having different things over different conditions?

Comment: `num1=int(input("Enter 1st No."))

num2=int(input("Enter 2nd No."))

print( if num1<=10:
    print("Congo"))` i want to do something like that

Comment: You want to print Congo when num1 is greater than 10?

Comment: Edit your question and put the examples there. The two answers below show you the two possibilities. Either you only print, if some condition is met - or - you print, but whatever is printed is determined by a condition. In the latter you will always print something.

Comment: The `print-statement` tag makes no sense in Python 3. `print` hasn't been a statement at all since Python 2; it's a function now.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This is a Python 3 question, but the dup target is a Python 2 question. (The answer's _basically_ the same, so I get why you dup-closed; just making sure you're aware.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use expressions like so:

```
print("A Minor" if age < 18 else "An Adult")
```

You can't "not" run the print at all from inside the print.

For more info you can view this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11880682/1658617). Keep in mind that it's a little outdated and `print()` is a function in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write

```
if age<=18: print(age)
```

Comment: like that's not what i am willing to accomplish.
that was just an example.
the thing i want to do is I am building a calculator and i have used 2 variables, and i am willing to use if condition in that like if user wants..........
Nevermind i just realised what i was trying to do doesnt make any sense

Answer (score 0):

You can write `if` outside the `print`:

```
if age <= 18:
    print(...)
```

This can be shortened to a single-line, though that can make for confusing code:

```
if age <= 18: print(...)
```

There's also an expression form of `if`, called a ternary expression. It requires an `else`, though.

```
print("young" if age <= 18 else "old")
```

You could also print the `bool` expression directly:

```
>>> age = 16
>>> print(age <= 18)
True
```