# How do I prevent a function from being called on NoneType, inline?

Tags: python, exception

I have a list of dicts where some fields can be `None`:

```
d = [ {'name' : 'Jimmy', 'surname' : 'Page', 'title' : None}, {'name' : 'Brian', 'surname' : 'May', 'title' : 'Mr.'} ]
```

I'm iterating over each dict in the list to do something (e.g. print it all as lowercase):

```
for item in d:
    print(item.get('name').lower())
    print(item.get('surname').lower())
    print(item.get('title').lower())
```

This of course will fail as soon as it encounters a `None` type:

```
jimmy
page
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(item.get('title').lower())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Without resorting to `try..except` blocks or using `if` statements for each key of the dict, is there a way to check if `item.get()` returns `None` before calling `.lower()`?

Comment: This is what you were looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880430/how-to-write-inline-if-statement-for-print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what I need to do this inline is called "ternary operator":

```
print(None if item.get('title') is None else item.get('title').lower())
```