# How to add if and else condition within a return in python? Similar to using case when within a Case statement in SQL

Tags: python, pandas, finance

Currently I have my function with if, return, elif, return and else return statement/conditions.

I would like to add couple **if and else condition within** my **return** in python. Within my calculation, I need to either add or subtract but  this depends different conditions.  I need help in  replicating the below SQL case statement in python.

```
SET AccruedInterest =
   CASE WHEN scheduleleg ='L' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END
   * Principal
   *(AllInRate /100)
   *(360 *(Year@(ReportDate) - Year@(StartDate) + 30 * (Month@(ReportDate) - Month@(StartDate))
      + CASE WHEN DAY(ReportDate) > 30 THEN 30 ELSE DAY(ReportDate) END
      - CASE WHEN DAY(StartDate) > 30 THEN 30 ELSE DAY(StartDate) END
   /360
WHERE Basis ='30/360'
```

I specifically need to add below conditions into my python function.

```
+ CASE WHEN DAY(ReportDate) > 30 THEN 30 ELSE DAY(ReportDate) END
- CASE WHEN DAY(StartDate) > 30 THEN 30 ELSE DAY(StartDate) END
```

This is my current function and conditions in **Python**.

```
#Accrued Calc for 30/360 Basis 
def accrued_30_360(row):
    if row['Type'] == 'L' and row['Current Filter'] == 'Current CF':
        return 1 * row['Principal/GrossAmount'] * (row['All in Rate']/100)* (360 *(Settlement.year - row['Start Date YEAR']) + 30 * (Settlement.month - row['Start Date MONTH'])
    elif row['Type'] == 'D':
        return -1 * row['Principal/GrossAmount'] * (row['All in Rate']/100)* (360 *(Settlement.year - row['Start Date YEAR']) + 30 * (Settlement.month - row['Start Date MONTH'])
    else:
        return ''
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working from top to bottom of your SQL query, you should work from bottom to top of it to simplify your code, since you haven't specified some of the fields in your DB, you might have to replace some of them below -

---

```
def accrued_30_360(row):
    extra_days = 0
    if row['ReportDate'].day > 30:
        extra_days += 30
    else:
        extra_days += row['ReportDate'].day

    if row['StartDate'].day > 30:
        extra_days -= 30
    else:
        extra_days -= row['StartDate'].day

    years = (360 *(Settlement.year - row['Start Date YEAR']) + 30 * (Settlement.month - row['Start Date MONTH']) + extra_days)/360
    amount = row['Principal/GrossAmount'] * (row['All in Rate']/100)* years
    multiplier = 1 if (row['scheduleleg'] == 'L') else -1 # update this condition
    final_value = multiplier * amount
    return final_value
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, it worked really well!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the inline `if` syntax:

[How to write inline if statement for print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880430/how-to-write-inline-if-statement-for-print)

For example:

```py
a = (1 if True else 0) + 5
```