# Inline if-else extension

Tags: python

I learned on the post [How to write inline if statement for print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880430/how-to-write-inline-if-statement-for-print) how to do inline if-else. Examples: Given assignment `a=True`, it expected the output `42` for statement `print(42 if a else 24)` and equivalent assignment `x=42` on assignment `x = (42 if a else 24)`.

Is there a way to use one further conditional statement i.e. `42 if a=='Hitchhicker' else if a=='Mountain-biker' 30 else 7`?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: `42 if a=='Hitchhicker' else 30 if a=='Mountain-biker' else 7`. But if there is more options it's better to initialize dictionary `d = {'Hitchhicker': 42, 'Mountain-biker': 30}` and use `d.get(a, 7)`.

Comment: It's not a statement but an expression, and all three parts of it can be any expression. You can go even further than `(a if b else c) if (d if e else f) else (g if h else i)` if you want your coworkers to dislike you.

Comment: Why do I receive "-1" votes? This is very annoying, community!

Comment: @molbdnilo I challenge you to answer "What should I do to make my coworkers like me?". I never found a great answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
42 if a=='Hitchhicker' else 30 if a=='Mountain-biker' else 7
```

Comment: Can you see how do I use `raise Exception('Some notification message.')` instead of number `7`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this way:

```
((7,42)[a=='Hitchhicker'],30)[a=='Mountain-biker']
```

Comment: I am inclined to check the above post as the answer. I thank you for the effort and alternative.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto No prob, just an alternative.